# Unable to load script.Make sure you're either running a Metro server(run 'react-native start') or that your bundle

Tags: react-native, android-studio, windows-7-x64

I want to start React native programming. so in CMD I tried r`eact-native init AwesomeProject` then tried `react-native run-android` but I had some errors that I could not find solution.
some of errors resolved by editing this project in android studio:
add `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` to build.gradle
and change `classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")` to `classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0")`
but emulator showed me

> Unable to load script....

showed in this image:
[error in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfnP2.jpg)

befor this message it showed me on my phone:

> JSIExecutor+JSCRuntime does not support Sampling Profiler

so I tried to create the assets directory in

> ...AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\

and run `gradlew clean` in my root project directory.then I tried

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

but this error is  occurred:

```
....error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[
\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\
\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more detai
ls.
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\
]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__t
ests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class....
```

and that error is showed me again in emulator.
I clicked Reload in emulator but it show me this error:
[could not connect to development server...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olBNZ.jpg)

i run `react-native info` for mor details and its result is:

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: Windows 7
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 740  @ 1.73GHz
    Memory: 892.99 MB / 3.98 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.11.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    npm: 6.11.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 25.0.0, 25.0.3, 26.0.0, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.1, 28.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.1, 29.0.2
      System Images: android-25 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.61.2 => 0.61.2
```

the screen shot of `react-native run-android` command is :

[CMD screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yUaG.jpg)

and logcat in android studio after runing `react-native run-android` show this error:

[first screen shot of logcat in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4XjA.jpg)

then i clicked on reload and logcat showed this error:

[logcat screen shot when click on reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnROX.jpg)

what is problem and how can i resolve it?

Comment: Is your Node Metro Server running?

Comment: I do not know what is Metro Server running. I followed "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html"

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in  (React Native CLI Quickstart) section or did you follow the Expo CLI Quickstart?

Comment: I followed (React Native CLI Quickstart).

Comment: also I run `adb -s 26EBB18531511866 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` in a CMD then run`react-native run-android`

Comment: I think you have not enabled usb debugging mode on your phone. Are you using a smart phone to run the project?

Comment: yes. i am using a smart phone and I enabled usb debugging. i tried to run react-native start that show an error **Invalid regular expression**. so I tried to unistall nodejs with `choco unistall nidejs` and install it again with `choco install nodejs-lst`. but error there is my problems.

Comment: The command to run the project is: react-native run-android. This starts the metro server automatically. Are you sure you have followed all the steps mentioned on the official website and have set all the path variables.

Comment: I sure followed all steps. some details is [here] (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26829). I rememberd when I run `choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8` I had an error to install python so I downloaded it and install python manually. I try to run `choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8` again. but it show me this: **Failures
 - python2 - python2 not installed. The package was not found with the source(s)
 listed.
 Source(s): 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources....**

Comment: You will have to download them manually. I have provided the links in the answer. I didn't face any issue myself. I manually installed all mentioned in the answer and it ran fine. During python installation, there comes a check box regarding python path, make sure you have clicked that check box.

Answer (score 1):

my problem is solved.

I tried to run `choco uninstall nodejs.install` and `choco uninstall npm` in CMD then I run `choco install nodejs.install --version=10.16.3` and `choco install npm --version=6.9.0`
when I run react-native run android I had other problems, So I opened my project in Android studio and add bellow codes to build.gradle:

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.2"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
```

of course that project had some warnings that using Android studio resolved them.

finally `react-native run-android` work correctly without error.
Adnan comment was helpful but I could not understand why:

> React causes lots of errors because of version incompatibility

when I followed official website?!

Comment: In my case after a fresh install in Windows 10, Metro Bundler crashed when typing ` npx react-native run-android`, so I just downgraded the node version as suggested and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The way how I ran React-Native for the first time is by following these steps mentioned on the official site:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

1) Download NodeJS from this link and install
https://nodejs.org/en/

2) Download Python from this link and install
https://www.python.org/downloads/

3)download JDK from this link and install
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

4) If you do not have android studio installed on your PC, download from this link and install
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
And later install SDK from within android studio

5) Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable
Go to Environment variables and create a new User variable ANDROID_HOME and add the SDK path to Variable path
The default SDK location: c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
If you changed the SDK location in step 4, add that path above

6) Add platform-tools to Path
Go to Environment variables and in User variables, click on Path>Edit>New
Add this path in the text field
c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
If you changed SDK location, then your SDK path/platform-tools

7) Install a nice text editor like this one, VS Code:
https://code.visualstudio.com

8)Goto Viw>Terminal in VS Code, run this command
**npm install -g react-native-cli**

9)Create a new project
**react-native init NewProjectName**

10)For running the project on a physical device, follow these steps:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device
OR use a virtual device like **Genymotion**

11) Run the project
 -Goto your project folder, run this in VS Code terminal:
  **cd NewProjectName** cd means change directory
  -Run the project: 
  **react-native run-android**

Hope this helps!
I ran my project without any errors following these steps

**IMPORTANT**
Do not forget to run VS Code As Administrator if your project is in C:/Users/.. folder because it needs administrative privileges to make changes to that folder.

Make sure Metro Server window is running. The Metro Server starts automatically after running react-native run-android.
See the picture below, the top window is the server window.
[image]

Comment: i do all of them but that problem is not solved.... i want to show more detail in a my question.

Comment: what do you want to know about my problem?

Comment: what do you think about downgrade node?

Comment: Kindly add a screenshot of the react-native run-android command in your question, so that the problem you are facing will be clear.

Comment: I added more details to my question...I hope to be enough.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the Metro Server running. The problem I found by looking at the details above is that your development server;that is Metro Server is not running. Do you have similar details like those in my answer?

Comment: thank you. when node window(top window in your screenshot) opened. it quickly closed. I could take a screenshot. So i fund there is an error:`error Unable to find React Native files. Make sure "react-native" module is installed in your project dependencies. If you are using React Native from a non-standard location, consider setting:( "react-native" :( "reactNativePath" :"./path/to/react-native"))in your 'package.json'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more detaile`

Comment: You have to go to the path where your project folder is located and the run the command react-native run-android otherwise it will not run. Like, if your project folder is in C:/Users/YourProject/..Then in cmd you have to move to the path using cd command. For example, cd Users, cd YourProject then react-native run-android.

Comment: Yes, i do that. I am in AwesomeProject directory and I do react-native run-android. The app is installed on my smart phon but has  that errors( their screenshots is in my question)

Comment: Try running react-native start, then react-native run-android. Lets see what happens.

Comment: react-native start has this error:`D:\AwesomeProject>react-native start`
**error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[
\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\........**
\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more detai
ls.
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\
]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__t
ests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class
    a

Comment: My node and npm versions are these. Uninstall your versions and install these versions. React causes lots of errors because of version incompatibility.
   Node: 10.16.3  
   npm: 6.9.0